# mounting EXT4 linux raid1 array with WSL2 on a windows host machine

Tags: raid, mdadm

Two years ago I created a linux/ext4 raid1 array of two 4TB WD Red HDDs to mirror my data. At that time I was using a small ARM64 device, and used mdadm to assemble the array. That small computer was used for network attached storage and has since been decommissioned, however I'd like to access this raid array on a new machine: one that has windows 11 as its host.

I am running WSL2 and ubuntu gnome and am attempting to find a way to mount the array. Using `wsl --mount \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1 & ...2`, I am trying to mount them but it says:

```
failed to mount (error code -22)
```

I did manage to mount a physical drive, and the output of `lsblk` on Ubuntu in WSL does yield the following, which suggests it does/can view the array, it just can't assemble:

```
NAME      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda         8:0    0   256G  0 disk  
sdb         8:16   0 339.8M  1 disk  
sdc         8:32   0   256G  0 disk  /
sdd         8:48   0   3.7T  0 disk  
└─sdd1      8:49   0   3.7T  0 part  
  └─md127   9:127  0   3.7T  0 raid1 
sde         8:64   0   3.7T  0 disk  
└─sde1      8:65   0   3.7T  0 part  
  └─md127   9:127  0   3.7T  0 raid1
```

When I try to assemble with mdadm `sudo mdadm --assemble --scan`, it says "no arrays found in config file or automatically".

`/etc/mdadm` does not exist for me to check the config but, even if I could, what would I be changing in the config?

What is the correct way to mount these devices in such a way that WSL can interpret the EXT4 format and see the array with mdadm? Thanks

---

(I don't know how to edit my post, sorry, new here)

I just want to mention that I did manage to mount a using `wsl --mount \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1 --bare` and `wsl --mount \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2 --bare`, and the output of lsblk on ubuntu in WSL does yield the following, which suggests it does/can view the array, it just can't assemble:

```
NAME      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda         8:0    0   256G  0 disk  
sdb         8:16   0 339.8M  1 disk  
sdc         8:32   0   256G  0 disk  /
sdd         8:48   0   3.7T  0 disk  
└─sdd1      8:49   0   3.7T  0 part  
  └─md127   9:127  0   3.7T  0 raid1 
sde         8:64   0   3.7T  0 disk  
└─sde1      8:65   0   3.7T  0 part  
  └─md127   9:127  0   3.7T  0 raid1
```

When I try to assemble with mdadm `sudo mdadm --assemble --scan`, it says "no arrays found in config file or automatically" /etc/mdadm does not exist for me to check the config. But even if I could, what would I be changing in the config?

Comment: You can [edit] your questions by clicking the "Edit" label under the tags. I've already updated the question to include the additional information, as well as some formatting for readability. If you could delete your non-answer, that will help keep things "clean" 

Comment: I do not believe `mdadm` is available in WSL. Is this an array that you would like temporary access to in order to migrate data? Or do you want to permanently mount and use the array with Windows?

Comment: @matigo On recent builds of Windows (Insider only?), WSL2 [can access block devices](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-mount-disk), so it might be possible, although I've never done it. I wasn't able to get it to work, as I'm using an older build of Windows, but if you have Windows 11 (insider?), you may be able to get it to work. What build of Windows are you running? You can check by doing Win + R, and typing `winver`, and pressing Enter

Comment: @cocomac I haven’t had Windows on any of my machines for almost a decade, so cannot test anything. The newer builds of WSL do allow mounting of individual devices, but nothing I’ve read points to support for `mdadm`. That said, if this is a temporary effort to extract data, it would be feasible to use a VirtualBox VM (or equivalent) and pass the devices through to the instance in order to rebuild the array. From there, data could be removed before wiping the disks so they could be used by Windows 

Comment: I am using windows 11. If virtualbox can handle the array then I would install a samba server on it to make it available through my local network. I built the array in linux and intend to keep all the data. i do not want to wipe it. Windows predictably doesn't see it , but that's ok. Mdadm appears to already exist on my windows-store downloaded ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Have you tried mounting `/dev/md127`?